# не работают media queries width (в то же время padding и color работают)

Tags: html, css, media-queries

У меня проблема с `media queries`,  значение `width` не срабатывает, вместо этого предыдущее значение продолжает работать - `.hero-text-box`. Я пробовал определить цвет с помощью тех же `media queries` и всё сработало. Возможно потому что цвет не был определен в основном файле `CSS`. ( у меня 2 файла `CSS`: *style.css* & *queries.css*).

[image: введите сюда код`]

Comment: Файл с стилями media подключен перед основным

Comment: Ай рахмет большой, Дружище! Я уже 3-й час голову ломаю))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Решение

В этом случае можно просто добавить предка перед селектором, который имеет выше приоритет, например `body`:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
    body your_selector {
         width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Или можно `!important`, но не нужно:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
    your_selector {
         width: 100% !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ого! Спасибо! Думаю пригодится.

Comment: @Magzhan пожалуйста, раз помог)

Comment: Nikita, сорян, Спасибо еще раз!